# How can I select and/or focus an input with JS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

#### How can I select and/or focus an input with JS or jQuery?

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="side-a-input" type="number" value="10">
<button id="button">Button</button>
<script>
$( ()=> {
  $('#button').click( ()=> {
    $('#side-a-input').focus();
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried:

`$('#side-a-input').focus();`

`$('#side-a-input').select();`

`$('#side-a-input').focus().select();`

`$('#side-a-input').select().focus();`

---

`$('#side-a-input')[0].focus();`

`$('#side-a-input')[0].select();`

`$('#side-a-input')[0].focus().select();`

`$('#side-a-input')[0].select().focus();`

None of them work

Comment: Have you debug and check the button click event function is works or call?

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache and try again? Your first example works on my end.

Comment: I found the issue: I was calling code which enabled / disabled inputs *after* I was attempting to focus the input.

Answer (score 0):

**It's working, clear browser cache, and try again.**

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="side-a-input" type="number" value="10">
<button id="button">Button</button>
<script>
$( ()=> {
  $('#button').click( ()=> {
    $('#side-a-input').focus();
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found the issue: I was calling code which enabled / disabled inputs *after* I was attempting to focus the input. Thank you for your answer. May I ask you how you created the "run code snippet" option? I tried for a while trying to get that to work to no use...

Comment: @Justin See [**this post**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) about stack snippets, and [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) about formatting

Comment: Thank you for the links. I never saw that button in my editor, and the button that supposedly replaced it didn't do anything other than tell me how to use it. The second link was very informative; thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

I had code that was being called afterwards which disabled / enabled some inputs, some of which were the input in question ( `attr('disabled', true)` ). So I simply moved the code that called the function to focus the input lower down.

Apologies for the stupid question. I can keep it up incase it helps others if the community feels that's appropriate, if not, feel free to remove this question or ask me to remove it.